# Google map v2 or v3?

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I started an app using Google map.I came to know that api v1 is deprecated.So i used api v2. It is working from android version 12 or higher.It is fine.But after sometime i read in some site api v2 is also deprecated and v3 is there.But when i saw v3, it was  related to html 5 and java script. So can anyone clarify me can i develop using v2 or i have to go for v3. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope you have found the answer. what you have used. so if I make an app using maps V3 and load it in android webview. so is this feasible and look like a native app's map?

Comment: @QadirHussain i don't think it will work and even if u will display in webview or something i don't think it will give that lok as native one.

Comment: So what is your suggestion that i must use Maps v2 for android? also I want to know there is no support for the Android panaroma StreetView like in iOS https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/ Look at the street View. I want this in my app. how to achieve this while using the Maps V2 for android

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hey, for Android Google maps API V2 is used and V3 is used for Websites and it can be used for HTML5 also, So you can Use maps API V2 for your android Application . check this **[link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)** for more Information .

Comment: so if I make an app using maps V3 and load it in android webview. so is this feasible and look like a native app's map?

Comment: So what is your suggestion that i must use Maps v2 for android? also I want to know there is know support for the Android panaroma StreetView like in iOS developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios

Answer (score 6):

Version 3 is for websites. The latest version for android is V2.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: off topic: Can't wait for May 19, 2013. So many websites are going to break.

Comment: @Iraklis what do you mean by that ? can you be plz more descriptive.

Comment: "Note: The Google Maps JavaScript API Version 2 has been officially deprecated as of May 19, 2010. *The V2 API will continue to work until May 19, 2013.* We encourage you to migrate your code to version 3 of the Maps JavaScript API." - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/. Upgrading from v2 to v3 is non trivial for complex applications.

Comment: But definitely that's not the case with android. The deprecated V1 will still work, but you cannot get a `Map API Key` now. Which means if you want to work with maps now, V2 is the only option.

Comment: @Iraklis yes as Archie said and also in my question i am developing android apps with google map.So anything to do with v3(which is web page based-javascript api)?

Comment: emphasis on the "off topic" part of my comment.

Comment: Won't be supported after May 19, does not mean that they will stop the service.

Answer (score 0):

[image: This is what Google says about GMapv3]

This is a screen shot from google developers page....
Google says that API v3 loads faster for mobile devices...

Answer (score 0):

- Google map v3 has been designed to load quickly and directly from the
  map server.So it provide latest updates in map without update your
  application.  Google map v3 display and control was based on html and
  javascript. It has a specific javascript api.
- In android, Map v3 can be implemented using webview and javascript
  interface.
- [here](http://javazerosign.blogspot.in/2013/11/google-map-v3-for-android-devices.html) a blog post for google map v3 in android.